# Fragment has null arguments safeargs

Tags: android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

How can I pass argument to dialog fragment using the navigation architecture component safeargs?
below is my current implementation

Start Fragment

```
val navController = findNavController()
val action =
            QuestionListFragmentDirections.actionQuestionListFragmentToCustomDialogFragment(args.templateFlag)
        navController.navigate(
            action
        )
```

Destination Fragment

```
   args.templateFlage //supposed to return a boolean value 
   //but throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment QuestionTypeDialogFragment{e8be5e1} 
   (47b305ea-35b2-49e0-b378-d31a08ba9a41) QuestionTypeDialogFragment} has null arguments
```

Comment: Please add your nav graph example too.

Comment: I am getting the same problem. Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: @GiancarloGatti no. I decided to go with viewmodel instead.

Answer (score 20):

May be you use args before fragment got it. For example I changed it in my code:

```
 private val args by navArgs<RadioDetailFragmentArgs>()
 private val stations = args.stations.toList()
```

with

```
private val args by navArgs<RadioDetailFragmentArgs>()
private val stations by lazy {
    args.stations.toList()
}
```

And it works

Answer (score -2):

Check out the instructions on [passing data between destinations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data):

In your navigation graph add an entry for the Dialog Fragment.

```
<dialog
        android:id="@+id/questionListFragment"
        android:name="com.path.to.my.QuestionListFragment"
        android:label="Question List"
        tools:layout="@layout/layout_of_fragment">

          <argument
                android:name="ArgName"
                android:defaultValue="@null"
                app:argType="boolean"
                app:nullable="true" />

    </dialog>
```

Then in declaration of the Fragment that can initiate navigation to this Dialog fragment you will need to add an action:

```
    <action
        android:id="@+id/actionQuestionListFragmentToCustomDialogFragment"
        app:destination="@id/chooseVideo"
      />
```

Finally in the fragment that initiates navigation you can call the function navigate:

```
val directions = QuestionListFragmentDirections.actionQuestionListFragmentToCustomDialogFragment(args.templateFlag)
findNavigationController().navigate(directions)
```

Note that the argument of QuestionListFragment we've set `android:defaultValue="@null"` which means that the boolean value can be null. If this is not the case then you will need to remove  it.

Answer (score -4):

You may send the parameter with a bundle instead of directions.

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putBoolean("templateFlag", args.templateFlag)

findNavController().navigate(
    R.id.action_QuestionListFragment_to_CustomDialogFragment,
    bundle
)
```